# Check for window.location.href.indexOf doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to call a page on my server every second, only if the current page the user is on is a `Create` page or an `Edit` page. But this code does not work:

```
function sessionRefresh(){
var remoteURL = '/path/to/file';
    $.get(remoteURL,  function(data){
      setTimeout('sessionRefresh()',1000);
    });
}

if(window.location.href.indexOf("/create" != -1) || window.location.href.indexOf("/edit" != -1)) {
    setTimeout('sessionRefresh()',1000);
}
```

The sessionRefresh() function is running on all pages. But I only want it to run if the URL has `/create` or `/edit` in it. Just to note, I'm not going to get this file every second on the production server. Its just for testing.

How can I rewrite this so that the function is only called on those create and edit pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a copy-paste typo, try

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("/create") != -1 || window.location.href.indexOf("/edit") != -1) {
```

instead of

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("/create" != -1) || window.location.href.indexOf("/edit" != -1)) {
```

Comment: oops! i can't believe it was a typo. my editor (dw) gave me no syntax warnings. thanks Nathan

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("/create" != -1) || window.location.href.indexOf("/edit" != -1)) {
setTimeout('sessionRefresh()',1000);
```

}

with

if(window.location.href.indexOf("/create") != -1 || window.location.href.indexOf("/edit") != -1) {
    setTimeout('sessionRefresh()',1000);
}

Comment: What's the difference with existing answer ?